# Rails - how do I confirm the version of a plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, version, updating, patch

I noticed that a rails plug-in I am using has had several fixes made to it, and im a little worried about all the other rails apps i have written.

Ideally I would like to have a script that can compare the checked out version of the plug-in against the repo version. Does anyone know if rails stores this info anywhere or if there is a patch/gem to add this capability to rails?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally the readme file of the plugin can contain the version . However this is the difference between a plugin and a gem . Gems tend to have proper versions , with plugin there is no such criteria . 
Also , I am not sure if you want to be upgrading to the latest plugin always as plugins are not always backward compatible and you run the risk of breaking your app .

Comment: I do realize that backwards compatibly can be a problem, But I think that security holes are the bigger issue. In the country I'm working from personal information leaks are about $100 USD fine per user thats leaked. Which is enough to kill the company instantly. If it breaks then too bad at least we wont get fined out of a job.

The best I can think of at the moment is downloading the entire git/svn directly and then generating a patch using the the new download so I can see what changed. But its too labor intensive..